# callback returning as error while its not erroring

Tags: javascript

```
exports.CheckPassword("Ender","plaintextpassword",callback) 
function callback(err, result) {
  if (err) {
   exports.Error("Password test " + err);
  } else {
    console.log("Password test " + result);
  }
}
```

When using callback(true) in the callback function it errors when it doesnt in the CheckPassword function
[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5SXuw.png)

Comment: Of course it does, as you are setting `err` to `true` and `result` to `undefined` if you call it like this. Try `callback(null, true)` instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Update]: As per the Node standard error is the first expected param and result/data is second. So

While instead of changing the function. We need to change the way we call the function.

we need to call it like below for success response

```
callback(null,true);
```

for error we can call it like below

```
callback(error, false);
```

Comment: The normal Node standard is `callback(err, result)`. The caller should change their approach, not the other way around. See https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#all_errors_error-first-callbacks. So technically this may appear to work, but it's non-idiomatic and confusing to Node programmers. Also, we don't know that `CheckPassword` isn't a third-party library that OP has no control over (if so, their parameters are in the normal order).

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. Have update my response accordingly

Comment: Thanks for the update. I wouldn't even recommend the second version, though. I would remove that entirely so there's no room for confusion.